# Find out if an emoji is usable in Discord.JS?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

As you can see in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoZTC.png), the bottom half of those Discord emojis in my server are grayed out. This is because I used to have two Server Boosts,  [but for now I don't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rcTt.png). I'm making an emoji picker for my Discord.JS Bot which needs to be able to detect every **available** emoji. Unfortunately, I don't know how to get my bot to detect if the emoji is usable. I also couldn't find anything useful here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Emoji. My current code:

```
let emojiurls = [];
await client.emojis.array().forEach((item, index)=>{
    emojiurls.push({"name":item.name,"url":item.url});
});
return res.json(emojiurls);
```

I probably need to use something like `client.emojis.available.array()` or something but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm not sure whether boost restrictions also apply to bots (e.g. that the bot may be able to use greyed out emojis)

Comment: I actually need a webhook to be able to send the emoji, and I've tested that grayed out emojis cannot be sent webhooks.

Comment: @ChrisSatchell Turns out that regular bots also aren't able to send emojis: https://i.imgur.com/ltgXszb.png

Comment: Discord emojis are sent as unicode characters, not as `:emoji:` strings. For more details check out https://anidiots.guide/coding-guides/using-emojis#but-what-about-unicode-emoji

Comment: I wasn't trying to send a unicode emoji

Comment: My apologies, it looked like you were in your screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the next Version of Discord.js ( v11.5 ) there will be a [`.available`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.5-dev/class/Emoji?scrollTo=available).

You can upgrade by running `npm i discordjs/discord.js#11.5-dev`.
This version upgrade should come with no breaking changes unless you are using deprecated features.

With this new property you should be able to do:

```
let emojiurls = [];
client.emojis.filter(emoji => emoji.available).forEach(emoji => { emojiurls.push({ "name": emoji.name, "url": emoji.url }); });
return res.json(emojiurls);
```

This can be shortend down to:

```
const emojiurls = client.emojis
    .filter(emoji => emoji.available)
    .map(emoji => { 
        return { "name": emoji.name, "url": emoji.url };
     });
return res.json(emojiurls);
```

Additionally, due to discord.js not changing the Version String in the Dev Branch, it will still sho 11.5.1.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask how do I add dev versions to package.json?

Comment: Nevermind, found that it's `"discord.js": "github:discordjs/discord.js#11.5-dev"` according to this which i found on Google: https://github.com/MoonlightCapital/InviteDeleter/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Ok sorry for the comment spam but although I added that to package.json and also uninstalled and reinstalled it with npm it still keeps installing the wrong version: `+ discord.js@11.5.1`

Comment: `npm i discordjs/discord.js#11.5-dev` should update it in package.json too.

Comment: I still get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'array' of undefined` because I think it hasn't installed the dev version... Please help me figure out how to install this, I'm still getting `+ discord.js@11.5.1` instead of `+ discord.js#11.5-dev`.

Comment: I update the answer with additonal information, I think you got something wrong, btw `client.emojis.available.array()` is wrong.